# In a networkx graph, how can I find nodes with no outgoing edges?

Tags: python, networkx

I'm working on a project similar to a random walk, and I'm currently trying to find out if it's possible, and if so how, to find out if a node in the directed networkx graph is "dangling", that is if it has no edges edges to other nodes.

```
import collections
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import random as rand
from collections import Counter


def randomSurf(G, moves): #with G as a directed graph and moves as the amount of "random walks"
    #rand.seed(15) #Random seed for testing consistency
    starter = rand.choice(list(G.nodes))
    currNode = starter
    m = 0.15
    #Construct list of dangling nodes
    list_of_dangl = [] #<- this is where I'm struggling.
    list_of_nodes = [starter] #List of all visited nodes, with the starting node already in it.
    for step in range(moves-1):
        if rand.random() <= m: #If the probabilty of going to a random node is hit
            currNode = rand.choice(list(G.nodes))
            list_of_nodes.append(currNode)
        else: #If the probability of going to a random node is not hit
            neighbours = list(G.edges(currNode))
            count = 0
            for _ in G.edges(currNode):
                count +=1
            tempRandom = rand.randint(0, count-1)
            currNode = neighbours[tempRandom][1]
            list_of_nodes.append(currNode)
            
    return list_of_nodes
```

Is there a way of checking if a node has no **outgoing** links in a directed graph? Or is there another method of doing this that anyone can recommend, that doesn't include using the networkx pagerank method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leaves have an out-degree of zero, so:

```
list_of_dangl = [node for node in G.nodes if G.out_degree(node) == 0]
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I was looking for to help me on my way. Thank you!